# References for real life applications on advanced EM

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, education

For EM (freshman level physics) and advanced EM (Junior/Senior level) to help students appreciate the material, I am looking for books/websites that contain:

1-applications of electricity and magnetism in real life. That is almost nonexistent in Griffiths, e.g. no bubble jet printers or magnetic tape in magnetism.

2-home experiments

Answer (score 1):

For the optics aspects of the courses, I suggest the book [Light Science: Physics and the Visual Arts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441931694). It's very real-world-oriented, with tons and tons of home experiments. Again, this is just optics, not the rest of electromagnetism.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring the speed of light using marshmallows or chocolate, there are countless examples online, e.g. [this one](http://www.physics.umd.edu/icpe/newsletters/n34/marshmal.htm).